# How to get sprinner value as integer

Tags: android, spinner

```
android android-widget
Spinner monthSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.expMonth);
String selectedmonth=(String)(monthSpinner.getSelectedItem());
int m=Integer.parseInt(selectedmonth.toString());//i am getting error at this statement
System.out.println("Exp-Month"+m);
```

07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309):     at com.main.bp.activities.CreditCardActivity.creditCardPayment(CreditCardActivity.java:51)
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309):     ... 11 more
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'January' as integer
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:433)
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:422)
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:382)
07-15 11:11:50.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(309):     ... 15 more

Any one can help me to get spinner selected value as integer

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Try printing the logcat here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the position of the selected item, I think you should be using `getSelectedItemPosition()`?

(Also in your above code there is no need for the `selectedmonth.toString()` as selectedmonth is a String variable.)